# Mutliple formatted text on pptx by using officer package on R

Tags: r, powerpoint, reporters, officer

Ciao,

I'm writing a code to generate an automatic report using officer package. I was wondering how and if I can write some text with different font. In my case I'd like to write some normal text and some bold words.

Let me show you what I get. I use these functions to generate fp_text objects:

```
fp_normal <- function(){
return( fp_text(color = "black", font.size = 16,
        bold = FALSE, italic = FALSE,
        underlined = FALSE, font.family = "Arial", 
        shading.color = "transparent") )
}


fp_bold <- function(){
return( fp_text(color = "black", font.size = 16,
        bold = TRUE, italic = FALSE,
        underlined = FALSE, font.family = "Arial", 
        shading.color = "transparent") )
}
```

I used to use combination of **pot** function by using sum operator and function **textProperties**:

```
pot("not bold ") + pot("and bold", textProperties(font.weight = "bold") )
```

> My question is: how should I combine **fp_normal** and **fp_bold** functions with **ph_with_text** function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have updated the package to make that kind of operation easier. Usage of `id_chr` is not easy and the code below give the advantage to not use it :)

```
library(magrittr)
library(officer)

fp_normal <- fp_text(font.size = 24)
fp_bold <- update(fp_normal, bold = TRUE)
fp_red <- update(fp_normal, color = "red")

pars <- block_list(
  fpar(ftext("not bold ", fp_normal), ftext("and bold", fp_bold)),
  fpar(ftext("red text", fp_red))
)
my_pres <- read_pptx() %>%
  add_slide(layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme") %>%
  ph_with(pars, location = ph_location_type(type = "body") ) 

print(my_pres, target = "test.pptx")
```

[image: result]

Comment: This version is not on cran yet and need to be installed from github

Comment: Only a very minor observation but I suspect `fp_redbold <- update(fp_bold, color = "red")` was intended, rather than updating `fp_normal`?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, at the end I think I've got it.

To apply different styles is in enough to combine **ph_with_text** function with **ph_add_text** function.

Namely **ph_add_text** do the same sum operator do for **pot** function. Keep in mind that, in order to refer to a certain line you have to provide **id_chr** argument. You can deduce the correct value by using **slide_summary(ppt)** command just after you run **ph_with_text**.

```
ppt <- read_pptx()
ppt <- add_slide(ppt, "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme")
ppt <- ph_with_text(ppt, "Some NOT bold text ", type = "body", index = 1)

slide_summary(ppt) # I see that the id is 2. Now I can delete this line.

ppt <- ph_add_text(ppt, "and some bold text", type = "body", style = fp_bold(), id_chr = 2)
print(ppt, target = "boldTest.pptx")
```

For the **fp_bold()** function see above in the question.
Ad this point we can add other pieces of text with different formats by keeping using **ph_add_text** (and maybe "\n" if we want write in new lines.

Ciao

Comment: ph_with_text will be deprecated in the next release